# Angular Socket.io: Form submission not triggering server side function

Tags: angularjs, socket.io

I'm taking a step by step approach in building an app which recognizes a selection from a ng-option drop-down menu, and on clicking submit triggering a server side function which returns the appropriate data from a postgresql database in table form. At this moment I'm trying to get the drop-down selection value passed to the server side function. So far I've got the client side behaving the way I expect, but when trying to activate the server side function I'm getting very little in the way of a response and do not even know where to start as far as debugging goes.

Here is the relevant code,

**dashboard.html**

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.4/socket.io.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/controller.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="dashApp_body">
<form method="POST" ng-submit="submit()", ng-controller="dashApp_ctrl">
<select ng-model="menu" ng-options="item for item in options"></select>
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="   Submit   " />
</form>
</body>
```

**controller.js**

```
var dashApp = angular.module('dashApp_body',[]);

dashApp.controller('dashApp_ctrl', function($scope){
    var socket = io.connect('https://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/dashboard');

    $scope.options = ["option0", "option1", "option2"]

    $scope.submit = function() {
        console.log("==controller.js submit() start==");   // THIS PRINTS
        socket.emit("getSomeData", $scope.menu);           // IS THIS EXECUTING???
        console.log("Option selected: " + $scope.menu);    // ALSO PRINTS
    };
});
```

**server.py**

```
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@socketio.on("getSomeData")
def handle_chatLog(msg):
    print("==server.py getSomeData start==")
    print("\tTESTING TESTING 123 ... msg={}".format(msg))
    return render_template('dashboard.html')

# start the server
if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, '0.0.0.0', port=8080, debug=True)
```

None of the server.py getSomeData debug messages print, however the following does print to the console each time the submit button is pressed

> "POST
>   /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Ljp1pG_&sid=5373cf4284c64360a3b65228ac898a83
>   HTTP/1.1" 200 -

I gather this indicates that the client side emissions are reaching the server but for some reason the getSomeData function does not seem to run.

I must apologize in advance for any bad form in code, besides python I have little experience with javascript, angular, or socketio. The concept of working with socketio appears to be straightforward unfortunately it would seem my implementation needs some direction. Any insight, advice, solutions would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Also wanted to add I am running this inside a cloud nine development machine if that could have any consequence.

Comment: Show the server-side code where you set up Socket.IO

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari As you advised I've shown socket.io setup. Hope this sheds more light on the situation. I would be surprised to see an error in the setup as I left it untouched from an earlier simpler socket.io practice project. This project still active but runs from a static html page and has it's own separate controller, perhaps it is causing interference with this one?

Comment: Ok. On the client, why are you connecting to the /dashboard endpoint?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari This is something I completely overlooked. While I was practicing socketio, as previously mentioned I got an example of a chatroom working with a static page and in that instance made that connection. When trying to replicate the setup I overlooked fact I was rendering from a template now. I've removed that connection and now see the debug messages from the service side function. Follow up question, I am wondering why wouldn't there have been some sort of error stating the endpoint wasn't found? Or am I not understanding the way the endpoints connections are handled?

Comment: @MariaInesParnisari Thank you for pointing that out to me. After a little tinkering I have the server side responding as expected.